# How to pass slrum command (sinfo) in os process sampler using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, operating-system

I have to make a jmeter script to connect putty and provide host name and click on connect which will open a cmd asking for user name and pwd.
Post which I have to type slrum command that is sinfo and it will retrieve data and finally an exit.
I have used plink to achieve the same.
In command parameter of os sampler,
/C
Plink -ssh user@host -pw password

I am able to successfully connect to putty and reach till pwd entry.
On typing slrum command in cmd manually,it is fetching result but the same sinfo when am trying to achieve through os process sampler it is giving error as sinfo command not found.
How to provide sinfo command from os process sampler to fetch correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is `slrum` or `sinfo` but I can think about some possible reasons:

1. You're logging into a session which doesn't call shell scripts to set the relevant [PATH environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), i.e. [this issue](https://github.com/fasrc/slurmmon/issues/4) suggests to add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH. I'm not sure how your installation looks like but you could try to use the full path like:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/sinfo
   ```

   or whatever
2. You might want to pass `-ssh` key to your plink to [force to use SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter7.html#plink-options)
3. And last but not the least, there is [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) plugin which don't require 3rd-party executables

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Yes with both ssh command and os process sampler am able to connect to putty and pass the required username and password. I have no clue on complete path of sinfo.Manually on just typing sinfo in the putty window it fetches result but showing command not found in os process and ssh command sampler. Please refer sinfo section of this link ::::: https://support.ceci-hpc.be/doc/_contents/QuickStart/SubmittingJobs/SlurmTutorial.html.The same sinfo response I want to achieve from jmeter sampler but it is not working.

Comment: https://support.ceci-hpc.be/doc/_contents/QuickStart/SubmittingJobs/SlurmTutorial.html

Comment: If something is placed in the local machine from where am operating then I can get absolute or relative path of it. Sinfo is application hosted system partition information so I don't know how to get the path. Any specific syntax to pass sinfo command is what am wondering.

Comment: [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(command)) command will give you the location of the executable, like `which sinfo`

Comment: Which command did the magic and finally am able to run sinfo command. thank you all for the help.